# How do I reflect changes made in one list onto another?

Tags: java, list, collections

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a backing list which gets all the changes reflected to it from other "sublists". To be more elaborate, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public abstract class User
{

    protected List<UserHandler> defaultHandlers
}

public class Customer extends User
{

    // All changes made to this list should the one from the parent class
    private List<CustomerHandler> userHandlers
}

public class Admin extends User
{

    // Similarily with this one
    private List<AdminHandler> adminHandlers
}

public interface UserHandler
public interface CustomerHandler extends UserHandler
public interface AdminHandler extends UserHandler
```

Is such a functionality even possible?

Comment: I think you could just use a regular `ArrayList` for this.  Did you try it?

Comment: You could do this by creating your own implementation of `List`, if you wanted.

Comment: From the [ArrayList Java doc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-)  "The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa."  Seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Agreed with @Mohsen; explain your actual use case, please. It seems like there might be a better way to handle the model.

Comment: @chrylis Updated the post with what I'm trying to do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to just use `defaultHandlers` in `Customer` and `Admin`, as it's already set to `protected`.

However, if you're looking for a sub-list of `defaultHandlers` that will modify `defaultHandlers`, you can use `List#subList`; from its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> `List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`
>
> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Keep in mind that you'll need to handle synchronization if your program is multi-threaded.